# Repopulating array with values in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to set up a lookup table in C, for programming pic IC's. I need to be able to write one block at a time, each of 32 words.

So I initialise my array:

```
uint16_t BlockData[] =
    {
    0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x11,0x11,0x11,0x11,
    0x12,0x12,0x12,0x12,0x13,0x13,0x13,0x14,
    0x14,0x14,0x14,0x15,0x15,0x15,0x15,0x16,
    0x16,0x16,0x16,0x17,0x17,0x17,0x17,0x17
    };
```

Then I write that data to flash memory.

Now I want to refresh the array BlockData with new values (all values at once as above, not with `BlockData[0] = 1stvalue;
BlockData[1] = 2ndvalue;` etc. etc.

This must be pretty easy, but I can't find it in any of the tutorials. Presumable if I use a different array without scrapping the first one I'm going to run out of memory pretty fast!

Thanks in advance for your help.

So my code so far (which generates errors when I try to repopulate the array is:

```
uint16_t BlockData[] = //initialize array
    {
    0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x11,0x11,0x11,0x11,
    0x12,0x12,0x12,0x12,0x13,0x13,0x13,0x14,
    0x14,0x14,0x14,0x15,0x15,0x15,0x15,0x16,
    0x16,0x16,0x16,0x17,0x17,0x17,0x17,0x17};

    FLASH_WriteBlock(FLASH_ROW_ADDRESS, BlockData); //write data to block
    FLASH_ROW_ADDRESS ++; //move to next block
    BlockData = //repopulate array with new data (this bit doesn't work!!)
    {
    0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x19,0x19,0x19,0x19,
    0x19,0x1a,0x1a,0x1a,0x1a,0x1a,0x1b,0x1b,
    0x1b,0x1b,0x1b,0x1c,0x1c,0x1c,0x1c,0x1c,
    0x1c,0x1c,0x1d,0x1d,0x1d,0x1d,0x1d,0x1d};

    FLASH_WriteBlock(FLASH_ROW_ADDRESS, BlockData); //write data to block
    FLASH_ROW_ADDRESS ++;
```

Surely there is a simple way to achieve this, I just don't know the syntax!

Comment: I don't think I understand.  You can set the values one by one (e.g. in a loop), or you can `memcpy` them from another array of the same size.  But none of those is going to "set all the values at once"; your machine almost certainly can't modify that much memory in a single instruction. And either way the new values have to come from somewhere - either already stored in memory, or computed on the fly (but you haven't said how they are to be determined).

Comment: Can you give a complete example of a naive solution to your problem (real code, not pseudocode) and explain why you don't think it would work in your situation?

Comment: It's unclear what problem you are trying to solve, so it's unclear how we can help.

Comment: If you want to copy the bytes you have to `memcpy(BlockData, (uint16_t[]) { blablabla }, sizeof(BlockData))` copy them one by one.

Comment: Is there some special benefit to copy new data into that array over using another array for second block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KamilCuk answered this in the comments above as well.  However, here is a simple piece of code that implements the solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int array[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};

    for(int i =0; i <5; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ",array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    memcpy(array, (int[]) { 5,4,3,2,1 }, sizeof(array));
    for(int i =0; i <5; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ",array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I need to read up on memcpy, but that's what I needed to know.

Comment: Feel free to mark resolved and closed if you have what you need.

Comment: @user1259492 upvotes (as soon as you will have enough reputation to do it) and accepting answers (only if the issue is actually resolved) is how we say "thanks" in this community. Consider marking the green tick on the upper left corner of Patrick's answer if it solved your issue.